# How to save Terraform output variable into a Github Action’s environment variable

Tags: json, continuous-integration, environment-variables, terraform, github-actions

My project uses Terraform for setting up the infrastructure and Github Actions for CI/CD. After running `terraform apply` I would like to save the value of a Terraform output variable as Github Action environment variable to be later used by the workflow.

According to Github Action's docs, [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) is the way to create or update environment variables using workflow commands.

Here is my simplified Github Action workflow:

```yaml
name: Setup infrastructure
jobs:
  run-terraform:
    name: Apply infrastructure changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
      - run: terraform output vm_ip
      - run: echo TEST=$(terraform output vm_ip) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: echo ${{ env.TEST }}
```

When running locally the command `echo TEST_VAR=$(terraform output vm_ip)` outputs exactly `TEST="192.168.23.23"` but from the Github Action CLI output I get something very strange:

[image]

I've tried with single quotes, double quotes. At some point I changed the strategy and tried to use `jq`. So I've added the following steps in order to export all Terraform Outputs to a json file and parse it using `jq`:

```
- run: terraform output -json >> /tmp/tf.out.json
- run: jq '.vm_ip.value' /tmp/tf.out.json
```

But now it throws the following error:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9
```

Even though the JSON generated is perfectly valid:

```json
{
  "cc_host": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "private.c.db.ondigitalocean.com"
  },
  "cc_port": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "number",
    "value": 1234
  },
  "db_host": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "private.b.db.ondigitalocean.com"
  },
  "db_name": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "XXX"
  },
  "db_pass": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "XXX"
  },
  "db_port": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "number",
    "value": 1234
  },
  "db_user": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "XXX"
  },
  "vm_ip": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "206.189.15.70"
  }
}
```

The commands `terraform output -json >> /tmp/tf.out.json` and `jq '.vm_ip.value' /tmp/tf.out.json` work accordingly on local.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After hours searching I've finally figured it out.

It seems that the [Terraform's Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hashicorp-setup-terraform) offers an additional parameter called `terraform_wrapper` which needs to be set to `false` if you plan using the output in commands. You can read a more in depth article [here](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/08/25/how-to-use-terraform-output-in-a-github-action/).

Otherwise, they will be automatically exposed to the step's output and they can be accessed like `steps.<step_id>.outputs.<variable>`. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs) and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context).

Comment: FWIW, if you're intending to use a string output value directly somewhere else then I'd recommend accessing it using `terraform output -raw NAME` because then it won't include the quoting and escaping Terraform includes intended for human readers to see the value in Terraform language syntax, and will instead just be the literal string value.

Comment: Do you or anybody have any example of github workflow which uses the steps output variable? The solution I used and all solutions I can see on internet guides to set `terraform_wrapper: false` to be able to get output variables, but your comment suggests that it's possible to get the terraform output from steps output, do you have any proof that it works?

Comment: I'm using :
`echo "$(terraform output --json)" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k].value)"' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`
I can access with `steps.<step_id>.outputs.<variable>`

Answer (score 6):

For me, what worked was using `terraform-bin output` instead of `terraform output`.

More info [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/167#issuecomment-1090760365).

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a beast! After trying the above, I wasn't able to get anything to work, so stitching together everything, I was finally able to figure out a way without using any extensions.

Here is my Terraform apply:

```
- name: 'Terraform_Apply'
  id: tfapply
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
  uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
  with:
    tf_actions_version: 1.4.6
    tf_actions_subcommand: 'apply'
    tf_actions_working_dir: "./Admin/Infrastructure"
```

steps.tfapply.outputs.login_server didn't work for me.

I'm using tf_actions_version 1.4.6, and I tried it with terraform_wrapper: true and false. However, what did finally work was setting terraform_wrapper to false and adding this intermediate step:

```
- name: 'Set vars'
  id: vars
  run: |
    printf "login_server=%s\n" $(terraform -chdir="./Admin/Infrastructure" output -raw login_server) >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    printf "admin_username=%s\n" $(terraform -chdir="./Admin/Infrastructure" output -raw admin_username) >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    printf "admin_password=%s\n" $(terraform -chdir="./Admin/Infrastructure" output -raw admin_password) >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

I'm using -chdir as my Dockerfile is in a subdir of the main solution, you could also use echo here as well if you don't need to format anything.

Then, the variables showed up without quotes (thanks to -raw) and I had access to them in a later step:

```
- name: 'Set Azure Login for ACR'
  uses: azure/docker-login@v1
  with:
    login-server: ${{steps.vars.outputs.login_server}}
    username: ${{steps.vars.outputs.admin_username}}
    password: ${{steps.vars.outputs.admin_password}}
```

This let me create an ACR from Terraform and then get these values so that I could use them to push the build image right to the ACR.

Here's my Terraform for completeness.

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "devportalacr"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = "eastus2"
  sku                 = "Basic"
  admin_enabled       = true

  tags = {
    Environment = "production"
  }
}

output login_server {
    value = azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server
}

output admin_username {
    value = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username
}

output admin_password {
    sensitive = true
    value = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password
}
```